# Saying Tehillim for a sick person

Tags: tefilla, minhag, tehilim-psalms, choleh-sick

There is a custom to say Pesukim from Tehillim 119 based on a person's Hebrew name when they are sick. (See, for example, [here](http://www.dailytehillim.com/119Tool.aspx?Sick=True) and [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1228223/jewish/Psalms-and-Jewish-Prayer-for-Healing.htm).)

How are these Pesukim said? For example, my name is דניאל חיים יצחק. Would I say the blocks of eight Pesukim for each letter in that order, including repeats? Would I do it alphabetically - אדחילמנצק? Would I go in order of my name without repeats - דניאל חם צק? Would I factor in ben (mother's name) in any of these versions?

Comment: I thought your name was דניאלף

Comment: Whenever I've seen it done at cemeteries, Yahrzeits and for Cholim, they repeat letters, not matter how often they reappear. No source, just observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the book 'Sepher Zechirah' (publ. 1709), which may be the origin for saying verses which begin with the same letters as a particular name, it instructs [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32230&st=&pgnum=57&hilite=) (s.v. סגולה ממקובל) the reader to read all such verses from the book of Psalms (not only from ch. 119; cf. intro. to HaKasuv LeHaim, s.v. ומה, by R. Haim Palachi - pic. below) in the order of the name(s), disregarding repeats and not alphabetically. This method has become known as [Likutei Tehilim](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjw-p-hwKLWAhVU1mMKHU6tDA4QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.otzar.org%2Fwotzar%2FBook.aspx%3F154268%26&usg=AFQjCNElNkPI9nl7F6sggQlHdE5CPOL0fQ) or [Tehilim L'Chida](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/47723) (R. Azoulai, a.k.a. Chid"a, sort of popularized it).

When praying on behalf of a person who is alive it is generally more accepted to add the mother's name than the father's, see [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=871&pgnum=77) for a discussion on this point. If you can get your hands on [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hebrew-TEHILLIM-COMMENTARY-ATERET-PAZ/391844570878?_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIM.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D46086%26meid%3D7190aac564ab4450b23187f0f96b1a64%26pid%3D100623%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26sd%3D371348887524&_trksid=p2047675.c100623.m-1) specific edition of Psalms, see the section of *halachot* n. 14, on this question and for a more detailed survey of this arrangement in general.

[image: HaKasuv LeHaim]